# navigation with login page

Tags: vaadin

I implemented simple application according of example simple login view. Where we have login-view and main-view. But now, how I can implement on main-view MenuBar where every Items when clicked open different views. And those views are under MenuBar in same place (center on the page under MenuBar, on sample) in main-view. I tried with additional navigator(which name can be subNavigator) in main-view but we must register navigator in UI(I have got appropriate error). Second solution is that I create UI and in init method  ManuBar and under it change every views(login-view, view1, view2 etc). But login-view have ManuBar and it is do not looks good. Is there any other way or are other ways to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear. I suggest re-writing it. Perhaps with a sketch image.

## TabSheet

Are you aware of the `TabSheet` widget? An easy way to switch between panes of content.

[image: screen shot of example TabSheet]

See the [Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.tabsheet.html), the [class doc](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html), and the [live demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/tab-sheet).

Also, look at TabSheet in the Reindeer theme as shown in [this demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme).

Comment: I wish something like sub-view in main-view. When I pres item from MenuBar in main-view I wish to see additional content under MenuBar. And I find solutino with one navigator registered in UI. And I have to extend main-view. But I have coming problem. How to add components like label on page after MenuBar in view from class that extends main-view class.

Comment: But now, how I can implement one main-view MenuBar where every Items when clicked open different views. And those views are under MenuBar in same place (center on the page under MenuBar, on sample) in main-view. I wish to see content from menu-view with additional content when press Item of MenuBar?

Comment: @vmaric [A] Your needs are not clear. You should post mockups. [B] You can add and remove widgets at runtime. This includes nested `Layout` objects filled with widgets.

Comment: I have already made: n=new navigator, n.addView("login", Login.class), n.addView("main", MainView.class), n.addView("view1", View1.class). After success login will be opened main-view with MenuBar in header of page. I wish that after click on Item of menuBar will be opened view1 and that MenuBar still be (or to remain) in header of the page(where it was)! Is this possible(somehow)?